# lookup a number in a data frame column and extract the row number of the cell that matched the number in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to do something that appears to be simple but cant find the function R that makes it possible.
I have a data frame with a factor column like this:

```
structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 4L, 2L, 10L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 
8L, 9L), .Label = c("01WEA8002", "01WEA8007", "01WEA8016", "02WEA8004", 
"02WEA8018", "03WEA8017", "04WEA8015", "07WEA8019", "08WEA8020", 
"09WEA8014"), class = "factor")), .Names = "A", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

I need a code that gives me the row number of a specific cell that contains a given number.
so say I have

```
n<-8017
```

I want the code to go the column and look in each cell for that number and when it finds it inside the string of one of the cells to give me the row number where it is located. So for my example (8017) we can see that the number can be found in row 7 of the column, inside of the string "03WEA8017".

The number I provide to the variable 'n' is always unique in the column, so there will always be only one cell containing that number at the end of the string after the word "WEA". The number before "WEA" can change but I want to focus on the number I have in 'n' and ignore the rest since it can only be one cell containing it.

So, basiacally I need the code to grab variable 'n', go to the column of the data frame, look for the number in each string and when it finds it, give me as output the row number where the matching cell is located.

I tried to be as clear as possible, thanks in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep("8017", as.character(dataset$A))
```

Comment: It turned out, after some tests that the number is not unique in the column I want to look up. Sometimes the number is part of another bigger one. For example "8017" is part of a cell containing "01WEA80178" as well as "03WEA8017" in my example, and when using `grep` I get a vector with both row numbers. Is there a way to tell R to only look for the exact number? I mean, look for a cell with the number I want exactly or maybe look then for the exact string "03WEA8017"? Note that is I use the entire string it also can be part of another so I need to look for the exact string, no more, no less.

Comment: Got it!. Using `^` to indicate the start of the string and `$` for the end. I used then "^03WEA8017$" and I got the result I needed.